# Is it possible to disable context menu items based on the selection on Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I will have some sort of nodes for a treeview as follows

Root
|-> some.txt(A text file which was added at runtime)
  |->Child(child for some.txt)
      |-> child1(child for child)

I designed my context menu with some options as New and Remove

What i need is when i righclick on Root, child or child i would like to disable the Remove option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a ContextMenu, you can handle the [ContextMenu.Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.popup.aspx) event and enable/disable menu options before the menu is shown.

For a ContextMenuStrip, you can do the same using the [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening.aspx) event.

For example, if you use the Menu item Tag property to determine if remove is supported (This is just for the example). You can do some thing like this

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if ((int)treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag == 1)
  {
    removeToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    removeToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But for selectednode.tag i am always getting Null value

Comment: Hey i set the tag property but i am unable to disable the toolstripmenu

Comment: @Dorababu, is the node selected in the tree? I tested this and it does work. Can you share some of your code? Did you set a break point in the event handler and check that the event is being fired?

Comment: Thanks for the code it works for me. I just use Convert.ToInt16

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove all the Empty sub menu items
int counter = MainMenu.Items[1].ChildItems.Count;
for(int i=0; i<counter;i++)
{
    foreach (MenuItem item in MainMenu.Items[1].ChildItems)
    {
        if (item.ChildItems.Count != 0)
            continue;
        MainMenu.Items[1].ChildItems.Remove(item);
        break;
    }
}
```